# html drag drop and replace existing image

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to make my code so that when you drag an image into a square with an existing image, it will replace the existing image.

```
function allowDrop(ev) {
  ev.preventDefault();
}

function drag(ev) {
  ev.dataTransfer.setData("text", ev.target.id);
  ev.dataTransfer.setData("width", ev.target.clientWidth);
  ev.dataTransfer.setData("height", ev.target.clientHeight);
}

function drop(ev) {
  ev.preventDefault();
  var data = ev.dataTransfer.getData("text");
  var nodeCopy = document.getElementById(data).cloneNode(true);
  nodeCopy.id = "newId" + Date.now();
  nodeCopy.setAttribute("draggable", "true");
  nodeCopy.setAttribute("ondragstart", "drag(event)");
  nodeCopy.setAttribute("ondrop", "drop(event)");
  nodeCopy.setAttribute("ondragover", "allowDrop(event)");

  var target = ev.target;
  var existingImage = target.querySelector("img");
  if (existingImage) {
    target.removeChild(existingImage);
  }

  target.appendChild(nodeCopy);

  var offsetX = 6;
  var offsetY = 6;
  nodeCopy.style.position = "relative";
  nodeCopy.style.left = parseInt(nodeCopy.style.left || 0) - offsetX + "px";
  nodeCopy.style.top = parseInt(nodeCopy.style.top || 0) - offsetY + "px";
}
```

The offsets are used to align the images with the squares. I tried to use removeChild, but that's not how it works.

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
.square {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 5px;
  float: left;
}

.clearfix::after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}

.draggable {
  cursor: move;
}
</style>

</head>
<body>
  <div class="clearfix">
    <div class="square" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)"></div>

--more squares here --

<img id="drag1" src="my_image" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" width="50" height="50">

---more images---
```

However, when I try to drag a new image into a square with an existing image, nothing happens.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a basic example. I replaced all the event attributes with event listeners. Now, when you create a new image you don't have to explicitly add event listeners -- they are in the parent element.

I don't know about all the `::after` selectors in CSS and the positioning of the image inside the div. Is there a reason why? Well, if you replace the float left property with some more modern flexbox it works fine.

```js
const container = document.getElementById('container');

container.addEventListener('dragstart', ev => {
  ev.dataTransfer.setData("text/plain", ev.target.id);
});

container.addEventListener("dragover", ev => {
  ev.preventDefault();
});

container.addEventListener('drop', ev => {
  ev.preventDefault();
  let data = ev.dataTransfer.getData("text/plain");
  let sourceimage = document.getElementById(data);
  let targetimage = ev.target.closest('img');
  if(sourceimage != targetimage){
    let nodeCopy = sourceimage.cloneNode(true);
    nodeCopy.id = "newId" + Date.now();
    targetimage.replaceWith(nodeCopy);
  }
});
```

```css
.clearfix {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  gap: 5px;
}

.square {
  border: 1px solid black;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.square img {
  margin: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div id="container" class="clearfix">
  <div class="square">
    <img id="drag1" src="https://via.placeholder.com/150/09f/fff.png" draggable="true" width="150" height="150">
  </div>
  <div class="square">
    <img id="drag2" src="https://via.placeholder.com/150/64f/fff.png" draggable="true" width="150" height="150">
  </div>
</div>
```